# How to get bound of StaticLayout drawn on canvas that fit its content?

Tags: android, canvas, text, boundary, staticlayout

I have a **StaticLayout** which contains some texts, the layout is drawn on canvas with translation, scale and rotation. I want to get the bound of this StaticLayout no matter how rotation level is.

If I save the bound of the layout with left, top, right, bottom of layout, and apply matrix with translate, scale and rotation to this rect when I draw layout to canvas, I got the bound that fit  the text layout but not its content.

[image: Image here]